# Lync 2010 - invite by email grayed out

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, lync-2010

How can I enable the Invite be Email function:

In the previous month, we use MOC 2007 with Office 2007 and everything worked fine. Now, after upgrading to Lync 2010 and Outlook 2010, it's been grayed out. I've searched for a solution but got nothing helpful.

Here my info :

- I use Lync 2010 with Outlook 2010.
- Outlook is my default email app.
- In Outlook I've enabled the Online Meeting Add-in for Microsoft Lync 2010.

Also, when I'm in a coversation, I want to invite other members by email (because some of them are offline), but Lync 2010 has grayed out the "Invite by email" option. How can I enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. You have to send at least one message in the conversation and then it will allow you to invite by email. Hopefully this works for you as well =)

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing on this myself and below are my results and findings. Hope this will answer your queries.

- If the audio device is not connected, and the user joins the Meet Now using “Audio” then the “Invite By Email” button in “participant actions” remains greyed out.
- Notice that the same “invite by email” button becomes active if you send any IM in the meeting.
- If the audio device is not connected, and the user joins the Meet Now without using “audio” then the same “invite by email” button remains active all the time.
- If the audio device is connected and detected in the Skype for Business client then “Invite by email” button always remains active irrespective of whether the user joins the meeting using Audio or without audio.

This is expected behavior.

When the audio part fails, none of the conferencing MCU is connected & there is no meeting info generated. You can validate by checking the meeting entry info.

To make this working when the audio part fails you need to send one IM so that the IM MCU can be connected and the meeting info will be generated post which you will get the invite by email option.